# Grid Views having data sets and table adapter are not accessible

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

Grid Views having data sets and table adapter are not accessible on client side. what should I do?
kindly help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: try using JSON  to transfer it to client side

Comment: Do you work with ADO or with ASP.net?

Comment: My answer helps you if you using ADO.net

Comment: soory , i am newbie and i don't know about JSON.

Comment: I am Using C# windows forms, having queries to access database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention client side I take from granted that this is asp.net WebForms.
 So  I suspect it has nothing to do with table adapters and dataset, asp.net have some rules to assign id to rendered controls, so my recomendation is to set ClientID property to your GridView in your aspx, and then use that same Id value in client side.

Comment: You sure that he askig about asp.net?

Comment: @НаташаКучерук, server side/client side concepts related to controls only apply for Asp.net WebForms AFAIK ;)

Comment: I know that:) Sorry, i only write projects on ASP.net MVC and never on Web Forms. And there we don't have Table Adapter. That's why anser like that. I Also oriented on tegs under question ----> c# winforms sql-server-2008-r2 . Sorry and thank you.

Comment: I think that he want some information about ADO.net(WinForms) / But that's OK;)

Comment: Sorry for late reply guys.
I am not using asp.net , i am c# windows forms.
Initially I assigned database/dataset to gridview's datasource by drag and drop, but then this client sided prob occured.
Now when i removed dataset, databinding, table adapter and then wrote simple select query and fill datatable with datset, then assigned datagridview's datasource to that dataset , it works fine on client side .. :)
BUT, my question remains, because I've designed reports using report viewer, in which i used dataset , and it is still not working on client side... :(

Comment: How are you creating reports? What you using? Your use some macros or something else.

Comment: I am using simple report viewer and then design a report.